# ActiveRecord ArgumentError: negative string size (or size too big)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been working with this one for a few days. Here's the ActiveRecord error and the application trace.

```
ArgumentError: negative string size (or size too big): 
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [ops_jobs_join].* FROM [ops_jobs_join] 
WHERE (work_center_id = N''M*1053'' OR work_center_id = N''M*1035'' OR
      work_center_id = N''M*1037'' OR work_center_id = N''M*1036'') AND
      (status != N''C'') AND (start_date != N'''') AND 
      (start_date >= N''20120516'') AND (comp_date <= N''20120527'') AND 
      (work_order NOT LIKE N''LA%'') 
ORDER BY work_center_id ASC, start_date ASC, starting_shift_num ASC, 
      status ASC, priority ASC, comp_date ASC, ending_shift_num ASC, 
      due_date ASC, sequence_number ASC'
```

It turns out if I call Op.all I get this error:

> ActiveRecord ArgumentError: negative string size (or size too big)

If I ignore the column that uses may contain unicode characters it works fine.  All the data is being stored in the database without a problem but for some reason rails3 isn't having it.

Some where clauses will return records while others result in the same error:

> activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:421:in `fetch_all'

It's similar to these two posts:

- [ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: ArgumentError: negative string size (or size too big): SELECT * FROM [shop]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999576/activerecordstatementinvalid-argumenterror-negative-string-size-or-size-too)
- [ActiveRecord doesn't work on one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651954/activerecord-doesnt-work-on-one-table)

It seems like the solution in the first post is to change the gem which I would like to avoid.

I looked at my table and I don't think I'm using any keywords as field names.

I use other queries similar to this one and they work fine.  The only difference is the values I use in the where clause (work_center_id = N''M*1053'').

Comment: This is probably because the collation on your SQL-Server database and the encoding that ActiveRecord expects to use are not matching.  See [here](http://www.archivum.info/comp.lang.ruby/2009-03/01906/Re-Ruby-1.9-OS-X-command-line-negative-string-size-(ArgumentError).html) for a similar problem. Can you post what they are?

Comment: The collation of my database is SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS and I'm not sure what ActiveRecord expects.  I'll try and research it.  I do know I have other databases with the same collation that work well.

Comment: I think the problem is one of my columns contains unicode characters.  The database is handling unicode fine but rails won't.  Though I understand rails is supposed to handle unicode.

Comment: Please answer your own question with the solution and accept it so other people can see it has been resolved. Editing the question title is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Rails default encoding for manipulates with data is UTF8, you need to use this encoding as well in your database.
Change it and all has to be fine.